# Is there a way to generate a list of dependencies automatically for nodejs script

Tags: node.js, nodes, node-modules

I have downloaded some nodejs script and there is no package.json inside. It works with a lot of npm_modules but this directory is huge and I'm pretty sure it does not use ALL of them.

Is there a way I can list all dependencies ACTUALLY used by this node script ?
in nodejs itself.

Comment: `grep -nHR --exclude-dir node_modules 'require' .` in project folder?

Comment: oh but I wish it were in nodejs itself :)

Comment: something like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/list-dependencies)?

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple package.json for your script (without any dependencies). After that you can npm module `dependency-check` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/dependency-check) with the `--missing` option.

Hope this helps.